# SQL Query to aggregate contract across product type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate

I have a table

| Product | Product detail | System | Contract Number | Date closing deal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cheese | gouda | Supermarket | 12346 | 11.03.2021 |
| cheese | gouda | Supermarket | 12345 | 12.03.2021 |
| cheese | Maasdam | Store | 67837 | 14.03.2021 |
| cheese | Maasdam | Supermarket | 67832 | 13.03.2021 |
| Tomatoes | Red | Store | 98237 | 13.03.2021 |
| Tomatoes | green | Store | 09123 | 13.03.2021 |

The question that I am trying to answer is how many contract are closed for Red and green tomatoes in store system, and Maasdam and gouda if it's from Supermarket system?

I have tried the following query but cannot figure out how to describe the specific criteria for the `System` field:

```
Select product detail, count(Contract)
from table where [product detail] in ('Gouda', 'Maasdam', 'Red', 'Green') 
Group by [product detail]
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What results do you want?

Comment: hi @ybyb please share your desired output format.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff 
the desired output is basically to calculate how much contracts are for each product detail for a certain system type, I thought of Select product detail, count(Contract) from table where produt detail in (Gouda, Maasdam, Red, Green) Group by product detail. But then the problem that i am facing is the condition of the system type

Comment: Why would you try to show tomatoes _only_ from the Supermarket and cheese _only_ from the store in the same output? Makes sense as two separate queries, or a rollup grouping, but it doesn't make a lot of business sense. Is this just a text book example? What topic are you covering, that would guide you on the expected method to use.

Comment: @Chris Schaller Why not ? this an exemple of data type that I am dealing with orgenized exactly as shown in the table below. the question Is not why the table looks like this but how to overcome that in order to have to count of contract numbers, do you have any idea how could this be solved ? thanks

Comment: Yes but that level of filtering at the same time doesn't make a lot of sense, so it is hard to image what you want the output to look like. You should include an example output that you construct by hand for the given dataset, then we can talk about interesting ways to return the data like that.

Comment: This, if I am honest, sounds like a homework question. Have you made any attempts to answer the question yourself? What were those attempts, why didn't they work? If you haven't tried you must have at least researched the problem (as that's a expectation prior to posting a question). What about the articles/tutorial/documentation you read didn't you understand?

Comment: @Chris Schaller, thanks for the explanation. I tried to simplify the data set that I have in this exemple. in the real one I have more then 300 product detail type, I don't need them all with the counting and on some it has to be more specific with the system type, but I got your point thanks again for your help.

Comment: Next time, it helps if you include a constructed output dataset and your attempted query in your post (not in comments) that makes the difference between the usual homework questions we see like this and a really good question. Bonus points for a fiddle or script to create the [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For questions like this, it is important to understand if you should be returning specifically only the 'Red' and 'green' tomatoes, or if the intention was to return all the tomatoes. It is hard to say with the given data set because there are only 'Red' and 'green' to choose from.

If your intent is to return all this in a single query, then you could try first to select the rows for the two distinct sets:

```
   SELECT Product, Product_Detail, [System], COUNT(Contract_Number) as Closed
   FROM Promotion
   WHERE [Date_Closing] < GetDate()
     AND Product = 'tomatoes' 
     AND Product_Detail IN ('Red','Green')
     AND [System] = 'Store'
   GROUP BY Product, Product_Detail, [System]
   HAVING COUNT(Contract_Number) > 0
```

| Product | Product_Detail | System | Closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tomatoes | green | Store | 1 |
| tomatoes | Red | Store | 1 |

```
   SELECT Product, Product_Detail, [System], COUNT(Contract_Number) as Closed
   FROM Promotion
   WHERE [Date_Closing] < GetDate()
     AND Product = 'cheese' 
     AND Product_Detail IN ('Maasdam','gouda')
     AND [System] = 'Supermarket'
   GROUP BY Product, Product_Detail, [System]
   HAVING COUNT(Contract_Number) > 0
```

| Product | Product_Detail | System | Closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cheese | gouda | Supermarket | 2 |
| cheese | Maasdam | Supermarket | 1 |

If you want those in a combine list, you can use a `UNION ALL` in between the two statements, or you can combine the `WHERE` criteria:

```
   SELECT Product, Product_Detail, [System], COUNT(Contract_Number) as Closed
   FROM Promotion
   WHERE [Date_Closing] < GetDate()
     AND Product = 'cheese' 
     AND Product_Detail IN ('Maasdam','gouda')
     AND [System] = 'Supermarket'
     OR [Date_Closing] < GetDate()
     AND Product = 'tomatoes' 
     AND Product_Detail IN ('Red','Green')
     AND [System] = 'Store'
   GROUP BY Product, Product_Detail, [System]
   HAVING COUNT(Contract_Number) > 0
```

| Product | Product_Detail | System | Closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cheese | gouda | Supermarket | 2 |
| cheese | Maasdam | Supermarket | 1 |
| tomatoes | green | Store | 1 |
| tomatoes | Red | Store | 1 |

---

What baffles me is why you would go to all the trouble to be that selective, surely there is more value in seeing all the products:

```
   SELECT Product, Product_Detail, [System], COUNT(Contract_Number) as Closed
   FROM Promotion
   WHERE [Date_Closing] < GetDate()
   GROUP BY Product, Product_Detail, [System]
   HAVING COUNT(Contract_Number) > 0
```

| Product | Product_Detail | System | Closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cheese | gouda | Supermarket | 2 |
| cheese | Maasdam | Store | 1 |
| cheese | Maasdam | Supermarket | 1 |
| tomatoes | green | Store | 1 |
| tomatoes | Red | Store | 1 |

This was computed with the following setup script:

```
CREATE TABLE Promotion (
  Product VARCHAR(100),
  [Product_Detail] VARCHAR(100),
  [System] VARCHAR(100),
  [Contract_Number] VARCHAR(50),
  [Date_Closing] DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Promotion (Product,Product_Detail,[System],Contract_Number,Date_Closing)
VALUES ('cheese','gouda','Supermarket','12346','2021-03-11'),
       ('cheese','gouda','Supermarket','12345','2021-03-12'),
       ('cheese','Maasdam','Store','67837','2021-03-14'),
       ('cheese','Maasdam','Supermarket','67832','2021-03-13'),
       ('tomatoes','Red','Store','98237','2021-03-13'),
       ('tomatoes','green','Store','09123','2021-03-13');
```

> **NOTE:** Given that all the records are *closed*, it is hard to test the date boundaries, so you should parameterise the date filter so you can test some boundary conditions to make sure your comparisons are correct.